# Scala Flink Join between two streams doesn't work

Tags: scala, join, stream, apache-flink

I would like to join two streams coming from a kafka producer, but the join does not work. I am use AssignerWithPeriodicWatermark to define my assigner and I try to join the two streams using 3 min windows. But I don't get any output. I printed the two streams to make sure they have events that are close enough together in time.

```
object Job {

class Assigner extends AssignerWithPeriodicWatermarks[String] {
  // 1 s in ms
  val bound: Long = 1000
  // the maximum observed timestamp
  var maxTs: Long = Long.MinValue

  override def getCurrentWatermark: Watermark = {
    new Watermark(maxTs - bound)
   }

  override def extractTimestamp(r: String, previousTS: Long): Long = {    
    maxTs = Math.max(maxTs,previousTS)    
    previousTS
   }
}

 def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment//createLocalEnvironment()
env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime)
val properties = new Properties()
properties.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9093")

properties.setProperty("group.id", "test")
val consumerId = new FlinkKafkaConsumer[String]("topic_id", new SimpleStringSchema(), properties)

val streamId = env.addSource(consumerId).assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(new Assigner)

val streamIdParsed=streamId.map{s =>s.parseJson}.map{ value => (value.asJsObject.getFields("id")(0).toString(),value.asJsObject.getFields("m","w")) }


val consumerV = new FlinkKafkaConsumer[String]("topic_invoice", new SimpleStringSchema(), properties)


val streamV = env.addSource(consumerV).assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(new Assigner)

val streamVParsed = streamV.map{s =>s.parseJson}.map{ value => (value.asJsObject.getFields("id")(0).toString(),value.asJsObject.getFields("products")(0).toString().parseJson.asJsObject.getFields("id2", "id3")) }


    streamIdParsed.join(streamVParsed).where(_._1).equalTo(_._1).window(SlidingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(60),Time.seconds(1))).apply { (e1, e2) => (e1._1,"test") }.print()
} }
```

Comment: Your description says 3 minutes, while the code says 3 seconds. Also, how do you know that the join should produce results? Maybe try printing the two streams to make sure they have events that are close enough together in time.

Comment: Thanks, I had already printed them, and it is all right. The code should say 3*60, I copied it wrong. I still don't know why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that You haven't set the `autoWatermarkInterval` and you are using the `PeriodicAssigner`. You need to do the following:

`env.getConfig.setAutowatermarkInterval([someinterval])`

This should fix the issue with Watermarks not being generated.

Answer (score 0):

Things that could go wrong (up to you to check them as you provided too sparse info to narrow things down)

1. No events on Kafka on either topic
2. No watermark progression on either topic
3. Your data operates on minutes and the code works on seconds

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. I have checked points 1. and 3., but I dont know how to check point 2.

Comment: You need to deploy it to cluster and then use UI to see whether the watermark progresses for given operators.